# My Website Keeps Logging Me Out When Clicking Link To Another Page

Tags: php, mysql, session, server, logout

I am having an issue with my website sessions. I built a website which requires a user to log in to view the webpage. It works completely perfect under my domain, but when I uploaded all my files to a different server the temporality let a client preview the web page on this server I get this issue i stated in the title. It automatically says the password is incorrect. You can still log in fine but if you try to navigate to another page within the site it logs you out 99% of the time.

I am using PHPSecurePages for my login forms so at the beginning of each of my web pages I have

```
 <?php
      // Connect To Secure Login
      $cfgProgDir = 'phpSecurePages/';
      include($cfgProgDir . "secure.php");
```

This Is what the secure.php looks like

```
// Create a constant that can be checked inside the files to be included.
// This gives an indication if secure.php has been loaded correctly.
define('LOADED_PROPERLY', true);

// Check if secure.php has been loaded correctly
if (isset($_GET['cfgProgDir']) || isset($_POST['cfgProgDir']) || isset($_GET['languageFile']) || isset($_POST['languageFile'])) {
        echo "Parsing of phpSecurePages has been halted!";
        exit();
        }

// include configuration
require($cfgProgDir . 'config.php');

// https support
if (getenv('HTTPS') == 'on') {
        $cfgUrl = 'https://';
        }
else {
        $cfgUrl = 'http://';
        }

// getting other variables

    $phpSP_message = false;

// include functions and variables
if ( !defined("FUNCTIONS_LOADED") ) {
        // check if functions were already loaded
        include($cfgProgDir . 'objects/functions.php');
        }
include($cfgProgDir . 'lng/' . $languageFile);


// choose between login or logout
if (isset($logout) && !(isset($_GET['logout']) || isset($_POST['logout']))) {
        // logout
        include($cfgProgDir . 'objects/logout.php');
        }
else {
        // starting login check
        if ($noDetailedMessages == true) {
                $strUserNotExist = $strUserNotAllowed = $strPwNotFound = $strPwFalse = $strNoPassword = $strNoAccess;
                }

        // make post variables global
        if (isset($_POST['entered_login'])) $entered_login = $_POST['entered_login'];
        if (isset($_POST['entered_password'])) $entered_password = $_POST['entered_password'];

        // check if login is necessary
        include($cfgProgDir . "objects/checklogin.php");

        // check if IP is allowed (if using IP-restriced access)
        if ($use_IP_restricted_access==true) {
                include($cfgProgDir . "objects/checklogin_ip.php");
                }

        // check login with Database
        if ($useDatabase == true) {
                include($cfgProgDir . 'objects/checklogin_db.php');
                }

        // check login with Data
        elseif ($useData == true) {
                include($cfgProgDir . 'objects/checklogin_data.php');
                }
```

it checks this php file (checklogin.php)

```
// check if login is necessary

// Check if secure.php has been loaded correctly
if ( !defined("LOADED_PROPERLY") || isset($_GET['cfgProgDir']) || isset($_POST['cfgProgDir'])) {
        echo "Parsing of phpSecurePages has been halted!";
        exit();
}

if (!isset($entered_login) && !isset($entered_password)) {
        // use data from session
        session_start();
        // session hack to make sessions on old php4 versions work
        if (phpversion() > 4.0) {
                if (isset($_SESSION['login'])) $login = $_SESSION['login'];
                if (isset($_SESSION['password'])) $password = $_SESSION['password'];
                }
        }
else {
        // use entered data
        session_start();
        // session hack to make sessions on old php4 versions work
        if (phpversion() <= 4.0) {
                session_unregister("login");
                session_unregister("password");
                }
        // encrypt entered login & password
        $login = $entered_login;
        if ($passwordEncryptedWithMD5 && function_exists(md5)) {
                $password = md5($entered_password);
                }
        else {
                $password = $entered_password;
                }
        // session hack to make sessions on old php4 versions work
        if (phpversion() > 4.0) {
                $_SESSION['login'] = $login;
                $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
                }
        else {
                session_register("login");
                session_register("password");
                }
        }

if (!isset($login)) {
        // no login available
        include($cfgProgDir . "interface.php");
        exit;
        }

if (!isset($password)) {
        // no password available
        $phpSP_message = $strNoPassword;
        include($cfgProgDir . "interface.php");
        exit;
        }

// login and password variables exist
// continue to checking them
?>
```

Comment: Generally sessions/cookies/etc don't survive across domains.

Comment: How are you storing sessions?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking, from this question we don't have enough information to help you. Please try and post some related code or a more detailed structure of your website

Comment: I just added some code

Comment: As @DragonYen mentioned, sessions/cookies don't survive across different domains. However, if you are handling sessions using a DB and if both of the sites are using the same DB then you can easily have one person logged into both sites. Just store a record in the DB with an expiration and on the second site, you can just check if it is expired